# Prove that $\log_a(1/x)=-\log_a(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I thought to write $$\log_a(1/x)=\log_a(x^{-1})=-\log_a(x).$$ But it has two problems: when x=0 and on the other problem it doesn't mention any condition. How should I solve it in each of them?

Comment: What do you mean by "when x.0" ?

Comment: Logarithm is not defined for zero and negative numbers anyway.

Comment: It is very easy making the sum equal to zero

Comment: If you follow the basic definition of logarithm, it will be solved easily.

Comment: The logarithm is undefined ones when $x=0$, so we can't prove it for $x=0$.

Comment: Solve for log_x . Show the stretching of the logarithm so it has base a does not change this.

Comment: log_x(x^-1)=-1=-log_x(x). log_a=log_x/log_x(a) is a multiple of log_x so behaves similarly.

Answer (score 7):

Exclusively by definition:

$$y=\log_a\frac1x\iff a^y=\frac1x=x^{-1}\iff a^{-y}=x\iff -y=\log_ax$$

Answer (score 2):

$$0=\log_a (1)=\log_a (x\frac{1}{x})=\log_a x+\log_a (\frac{1}{x})$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^y$: then $\ln(1/e^y)=\ln(e^{-y})=-y$.

Answer (score -1):

log_x(x^-1)=-1=-log_x(x). log_a=log_x/log_x(a) is a multiple of log_x so behaves similarly.

Comment: This is very difficult to read, and would not be if you were to format it with Mathjax.

Comment: Enough is enough. @T.Bongers This is getting out of hand...this user's behavior.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I didn't recognize them after the username change. To alephnull: One of the points brought up in your recent meta post was specifically about how a consistent lack of *any* apparent effort in formatting might be a reason you get a poor response.

Comment: @T.Bongers FWIW, I just created a [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24786/when-a-user-refuses-to-typeset-responses-and-posts-numerous-low-quality-answers) on meta...hopefully there will be some resolution to this nonsense. It is starting to bother me more than it should perhaps.

Comment: @Alephnull I have been quite "chill" for a while now...some people care about this site and maintaining it as one of the best math resources available. It should be kept that way, and all you have to do is what is expected of all users here to make it a pleasurable experience. It is unclear to me why you refuse to put any effort into making your work readable.